# How can you clone a node and all its children with a single click in Drupal?

Tags: module, drupal, nodes, children, cloning

Drupal 10 Newbie here.
I know Drupal has "modules" which are similar in concept to plugins in Wordpress and Joomla I suppose.
I also know there are multiple modules which allow you to clone nodes (or content in general).
My specific question though is: can I clone a node **AND** all its subcontent (children) with the same click/operation?

I've found conflicting information on this specific function but it would seem crazy to me that there is no way to do it in Drupal 10.
Supposing I'm right, does anybody have a specific module to sugggest that would allow me to do that with a single click?

Comment: Realize Drupal 9 is the current version, so you may not find support/compatibility for D10 now. One option for what you're doing is entity_clone module. Two questions: 1. what are the children? Things like Paragraphs do not always allow easy "cloning". 2. Are you cloning so that you can modify? Or can you reference the current entity without having to clone? Drupal's entity system is pretty flexible for that sort of content pattern. Avoid copying what you don't need to.

Comment: I'll give a look to the entity_clone module, thanks!

I have created a simple structure consistant in a node page that contains several other custom pages.
I'll have to make this exact same structure multiple times, two for each of the past 20 years, and for future years too.
I want to be able to clone with a click this node and all the pages it contains. Once I have cloned it, I can start modyfing the cloned one and putting in all the specific data.
If I had to re-create all of this every time I would waste a ton of time.

Does it make any sense? Hopefully so.

Comment: Yes that may work. Another option is to modify the default value for your node fields, so they are not empty/blank. For example, you can add section headings or other text to a Body field, so that each new piece of content uses that to start. An editor can modify or remove, but it can reduce the work required to start. Maybe that works with your content structure.

Comment: That's an interesting approach I didn't think of. Givin me lot of food for thought. Thanks a lot for your contributions Brian!